# implementing the 1 out of 2 oblivious transfer protocol in c#

Tags: c#, rsa, modulo, rsacryptoserviceprovider

Implementation of  [1-2 oblivious transfer protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivious_transfer#1-2_oblivious_transfer) for RSA requires a calculation of 
 [image: v](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/5/b/2/5b2f29ecb81e9dcd95061b333f2e6f2c.png). If we'd have previously used the class <code>RSACryptoServiceProvider</code>, for calculating [![x]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLbf5.png)
<sub>(source: [rogercortesi.com](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/tempimagedir/eqn2380.png))</sub>
 and [image: k]
<sub>(source: [rogercortesi.com](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/tempimagedir/eqn2758.png))</sub>
, then the results would be `byte[]` arrays. How would one perform the addition and the modulo operation of the 2 arrays? Is using  `BitConverter.ToInt32()` useful at all in this case?

Comment: I think you probably don't want to go to `Int32`s. You need to figure out how to to addition on the byte arrays directly. I'm not sure if C# provides a nice way to do this. I guess you could just add them up byte-by-byte, then handling any overflow, and construct a new byte array in that fashion.

Comment: yes adding byte by byte seems logical, but what about modulo operation?

Comment: yeah. fair enough. have you tried looking at - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method ?

Comment: Why don't you use the [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) class?